# Как выровнять текст?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function Scroll() {
 var top=document.getElementById('header');
 var ypos=window.pageYOffset;
 if (ypos>800) {1
  // top.style.opacity = "0";
  top.style.height=100+'px';
 }
 else {
  // top.style.opacity= "1";
  top.style.height=150+'px';
 }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #57C7AE;
  box-shadow: 2px #ccc;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

div {
  height: 2000px;
}

#text div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#text {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Scroll Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
  <div id="text">
   <div>Lorem1</div>
   <div>Lorem2</div>
   <div>Lorem3</div>
   <div>Lorem4</div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как поставить тесту отступ справа 40px  и выровнять вертикально по центру

Answer (score 0):

Для выравнивания используйте Flexbox. Куда нужен отступ, я не понял.

`div { height: 2000px;}` - работает на все div'ы с соответствующим результатом

```js
function Scroll() {
 var top=document.getElementById('header');
 var ypos=window.pageYOffset;
 if (ypos>800) {1
  // top.style.opacity = "0";
  top.style.height=100+'px';
 }
 else {
  // top.style.opacity= "1";
  top.style.height=150+'px';
 }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #57C7AE;
  box-shadow: 2px #ccc;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

#wall{
  height: 2000px;
}

#text div {
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#text {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Scroll Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
  <div id="text">
   <div>Lorem1</div>
   <div>Lorem2</div>
   <div>Lorem3</div>
   <div>Lorem4</div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div id='wall'>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```